# Changing column data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm searching for a way to change/create a new column from existing query column for multiply strings.

My original column looks like this:

```
    parttype_name
    ---------------
    MY 4KXDVV F H
    MY 4KXDVV F H
    MY 4KXDVV F H
    MY 4KXDVV F H
    A4 4BXDCV C X
    A4 4BXDCV C X
    A4 4BXDCV C X
    A4 4BXDCV C X
    A4 4BXDCV C X
```

What I'm asking for is to find a simple way  in one string (if possible) to update/create new column for the next data: (if column data is 'MY 4KXDVV F H' then update it to H5, if 'A4 4BXDCV C X' then update it to X3... and so own for all column strings.

Thanks,

Comment: Not getting, 'MY 4KXDVV F H' then update it to H5 - it would be specific value to update with H5?

Comment: Could you explain the logic for the updating? Or it is hard-code?

Comment: Please, elaborate, why `H5` and why `X3`.

Comment: all data that came for the query presented at power pivot, there I need to combine all "FH" rows to one total row. I think the best option for it to edit query results.

Comment: @Coldfire what is logic of this H5, X3 etc?? If you share the logic - someone may provide answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try the **replace** function like this:

```
select parttype_name,
       replace(parttype_name,'MY','H5') as edited_parttype_name 
from MyTable
```

**Edit:**
You can nest the calls to replace, like this:

```
select parttype_name,
       replace(
       replace(
       replace(parttype_name,
       'MY','H5'),
       'YY','H4'),
       'ZZ','H3')
       as edited_parttype_name 
from MyTable
```

Just take care of the opening-closing parenthesis

Comment: It is like he needs to do more work to find out unique values and make a longer query to update those dynamic values...

Comment: can I do it for more then one parmeter in one code row?
For example to add to it  replace(parttype_name,YY,'H4') as edited_parttype_name

Answer (score 0):

May be you want [CASE STATEMENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
SELECT
    parttype_name,
    CASE parttype_name 
        WHEN 'MY 4KXDVV F H' THEN 'H5'
        WHEN 'A4 4BXDCV C X' THEN 'X3'
        --WHEN '' THEN ''
    END
FROM
    your_table;
```

Comment: It is like he needs to do more work to find out unique values and make a longer query to update those dynamic values

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest if you have more no. of records then get distinct values (parttype_name) and then use while loop or make a cursor to update all those values with specific values like in your example H5 and H4.

```
UPDATE TableName
SET parttype_name = REPLACE(parttype_name, @variablename, @updatevalue)
```

Here ,@variablename and @updatevalue would be variables you can use some logic to change value of @updatevalue dynamically.

*Let me know if you need more help.*

Comment: Yes I have more, I cannot update the table due to permission issue. How can I create a new updated column with your while loop? (+ for more than one part type, meaning how the syntax should look like)

Comment: I am just thinking you can use of temp table, insert all the data using while loop to it and then insert that column from temp table to existing one using some where condition.